# What's the right way to pass this database result into a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am grabbing a string from a `"title"` field and passing it to an `addText` javascript function.
I am having trouble passing the string properly though. This--->

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($part_result)){

 echo "<div id ='link' onclick = 'addText("$row['title']");'>" . $row['title'] ."</div>";

}
```

yields a syntax error.
`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting ',' or ';'`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `echo '<div id="link" onclick="addText(\''.$row['title'].'\')">'.$row['title'].'</div>';` ?

Comment: There's no "best way", simply a correct way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo "<div id ='link' onclick = 'addText(\"".$row['title']."\");'>" . $row['title'] ."</div>";
```

Comment: You'll need to avoid potential javascript syntax errors by properly escaping any quotes in `$row['title']`

Comment: sure, any output should be cleared by htmlspecialchars but I don't use it as OP.

Answer (score 2):

You error is coming from the fact that you're not properly concatenating your static strings to your variables in all places.

```
echo "<div id ='link' onclick = 'addText("$row['title']");'>" . $row['title'] ."</div>";
```

Should be

```
echo '<div id="link" onclick="addText( \'' . $row['title'] . '\' );">' . $row['title'] . '</div>';
```

Also, since `$row['title']` is being used inside of an HTML attr, it should be entitized to avoid quote collisions:

```
echo '<div id="link" onclick="addText( \'' .htmlentities( $row['title'], ENT_QUOTES ) . '\' );">' . $row['title'] . '</div>';
```

And for the cleanest code I'd use `printf()`:

```
printf( '<div id="link" onclick="addText( \'%s\' );">%s</div>', htmlentities( $row['title'], ENT_QUOTES ), $row['title'] );
```

Comment: `htmlentities` with `ENT_QUOTES` won't prevent single quote collision. `&#039;` will be treated as a single quote by the JS parser. +1 for at least mentioning the issue.

Comment: Ha, yeah, I was in a hurry and only thinking about the collision with the HTML quotes. But I believe you're right, more work needs to be done to avoid collisions between the 3 involved langs/envs. Thanks a lot for the vote!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
echo '<div id="link" onclick="addText(\''.$row['title'].'\')">'.$row['title'].'</div>';
```

You don't need the `;` after `addText()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode` to pass your title through.  This will encode it just in case you have single or double quotes (or any other bad character) in it.

Also your error is coming from the variable itself.  Since your are using double quotes, wrap your variable with curly brackets:

```
addText('{$row['title']}');
```